# Proper way and place to unzip and install software at in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: 14.10

I am new to Ubuntu and am trying to install ElasticSearch on Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit. The instructions are on this page [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elkdownloads/)  and seem simple enough. 
However, I have tried to install programs while not using the standard Synaptic before and have always goofed it up.

So my first question is this. In the directions it says to simply download the package(done) then unzip and then Run `bin/elasticsearch` on Unix. So when I downloaded the package it is now in my downloads folder, should I unzip it here or move it to bin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract your downloaded file right there or wherever you want.There is no need to move your downloaded file into `/bin` directory.

`bin/elasticsearch` doesn't mean `/bin/elasticsearch`, what it is saying that you will find bin directory inside the extracted  folder and you need to execute the file `elasticsearch` which is present in this directory.

Answer (score 1):

The binary packages on the page that you mention are intended for use on 'generic' Unix systems, where you have no software management system, or don't want to use one. However, Ubuntu's software management is excellent.

I would advise to stay away from the binary versions, and instead go to the [Repositories](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html) guide. Enter the commands under `apt`. That way, you don't need to worry about where to put the files. Also, if you change your mind, you can easily remove the package from your system.

Answer (score 1):

Download the elasticsearch-1.4.2.deb file from the [elasticsearch.org download](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elkdownloads/) webpage, and then double-click it to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center. It doesn't matter what folder you download it to. Since it's a .deb file, double-clicking it will open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center and when you install it, it will be installed the same, no matter what folder the .deb file was located in to begin with.